# Codename one build error

Tags: java, compilation, codenameone

I've reached such a problem yesterday:

I'm trying to build an app on the server, but I'm getting this **error**:

> `[codeNameOne] java.io.IOException: An upload error occured - check
>   that you have enough build credits on the server` ... BUILD FAILED
>   `/home/arsenii/Code/IDE workspaces/own_workspace/EGuide/build.xml:452:
>   Error in server build process`"

I have't compiled apps this month yet.

What it could be, and why?

Thank you in advance.

```
IDE: Eclipse

Desktop OS - Ubuntu 12.04
```

Comment: `check that you have enough build credits on the server .` Isn't it a clue ?

Comment: Sure, but I have no compilations this month. Last one was on 3.08, more than month ago. And on the codename one website is written, that all free users have 100 compilations every month. Can it be anything else?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy setting and whether you might have a communication issue.

Check if there is a more detailed stack.

Make sure you are using Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue as this and it was because I had changed the ant build file so that it was setting the java source and java target to 1.7 and not the default 1.5.

It seems that the build server doesn't like anything above 1.5